# Iterate through Huge XML File and get the Value?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, data-processing

I wanna Iterate through the Users Stackoverflow dump File. The problem is it is very Huge and it is XML. For me xml is a new Topic. I read several Documentation and Stackoverflow Post but for some reason it doesn't work.

XML Format:

```
<users>
  <row Id="-1" Reputation="1" 
  CreationDate="2008-07-31T00:00:00.000" 
  DisplayName="Community" 
  LastAccessDate="2008-08-26T00:16:53.810" 
  WebsiteUrl="http://meta.stackexchange.com/" 
  Location="on the server farm" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Hi, I'm not really a person.&" Views="649" UpVotes="245983" DownVotes="924377" AccountId="-1" 
  />
</users>
```

The Code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

for evt, elem in iterparse('data/Users.xml', events=('start','end')):
    print(evt, elem)
```

What I get:

The For Loop outprint me a bunch of hexacode. And in the End I get an Memory Exception. Maybe its normal because I try it a second time and it iterate the xml very fast `0.13 seconds`

```
start <Element 'row' at 0x04CC16F0>
end <Element 'row' at 0x04CC16F0>
start <Element 'row' at 0x04CC1810>
```

I hope you guys can help by the Question. How I get the Value of this Output? I wanna save it into SQL.

All of the File is 199 GB (Badge,Comment,PostLinks,PostHistory,Users,Posts,Tags and Votes). 
The Users.xml specific for this Question is 2,49 GB. But I wanna put all of the Data From SO into the database.

Yours faithfully

HanahDevelope

Comment: "Huge" means nothing. 1Mb or 1Tb? Give us the numbers.

Comment: All of the File is 199 GB (Badge,Comment,PostLinks,PostHistory,Users,Posts,Tags and Votes). The Users.xml specific for this Question is 2,49 GB. But I wanna put all of the Data From SO into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to loop through the `end` event for all `row` elements and do something with the attributes:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

for evt, elem in iterparse('data/Users.xml', events=('end',)):
    if elem.tag == 'row':
        user_fields = elem.attrib
        print(user_fields)
```

This will output:

```
{'DisplayName': 'Community', 'Views': '649', 'DownVotes': '924377', 'LastAccessDate': '2008-08-26T00:16:53.810', 'Id': '-1', 'WebsiteUrl': 'http://meta.stackexchange.com/', 'Reputation': '1', 'Location': 'on the server farm', 'UpVotes': '245983', 'CreationDate': '2008-07-31T00:00:00.000', 'AboutMe': "<p>Hi, I'm not really a person.", 'AccountId': '-1'}
```

Comment: I will not asume something. But is it on purpose that you dont write 'start' at events?

Comment: Every XML node is going to trigger both a `start` and `end` event, so you only really need to handle one of them. When the `start` event fires it's not guaranteed that all the attributes of the current XML node have been processed yet, so the safer approach is to only handle the `end` event.

Comment: Even using this approach the RAM usage increases dramatically. Could you tell me why and help me figure out how to work around it?